# Datepicker with multiple dates by dragging the mouse

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Does anyone know a way to select multiple dates by dragging the mouse with the button clicked on the calendar and select how many dates i want, then just release the mouse and dates are selected?

Comment: https://github.com/mattiasarro/jquery-ui-daterange-draggable

Comment: Thanks, but this only takes a period of dates, I need to be able to pick up various periods